# How is Abaqus Command different from cmd or PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, cmd, abaqus

I've been running hundreds of Abaqus simulations, during which Abaqus has been crashing randomly in the middle of jobs. The jobs are submitted for analysis in a python script loop, and the script is called through Windows PowerShell.
I looked everywhere for a solution to the random crashing issue without any luck. Then, by chance, I found out that Abaqus has its own **(Abaqus Command)**, which I've been using for a couple of hours now without any interruptions. So, I'm wondering if this has solved my problem, and I want to know if, and how, **Abaqus Command** may be different from the Windows PowerShell or the usual cmd.
\Thanks.

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/programs/fe/abaqus/faq68/OldUserSubConfigureInfo.html) suggests that it is simply a  `cmd.exe` instance with custom configuration.

Comment: Assuming that the customization is based on _environment variables_, you should be able to enter a PowerShell session from that `cmd.exe` instance and get the same customization.

Comment: An update... the script has been running for over 14 hours so far without Abaqus stopping. So, using the Abaqus Command does seem to have fixed the problem. In any case, the question still remains.